# For loop and Append to update a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to update a List, using a For-statement. It doesn't work as I expect.

my data is like:

```
data = {{1, 11, 12, 13}, {1, 14, 15, 16}, {1, 17, 18, 19}, {2, 21, 22,
    23}, {2, 24, 25, 26}, {2, 27, 28, 29}, {3, 31, 32, 33}, {3, 34, 
   35, 36}, {3, 37, 38, 39}};

set = {"A", "B", "C"};
```

The desired output is:

```
{{1, 11, 12, 13, A}, {1, 14, 15, 16, A}, {1, 17, 18, 19, A}, {2, 21, 
  22, 23, B}, {2, 24, 25, 26, B}, {2, 27, 28, 29, B}, {3, 31, 32, 33, 
  C}, {3, 34, 35, 36, C}, {3, 37, 38, 39, C}}
```

My idea was:

```
For[i = 2, i <= Length[set], i++,
  Map[Append[#, set[[i]]] &, Select[data, #[[1]] == i &]]
  ];
```

But it does not give te output.

When I do the same

```
i = 1;
Map[Append[#, set[[i]]] &, Select[data, #[[1]] == i &]]
```

I get:

```
{{1, 11, 12, 13, "A"}, {1, 14, 15, 16, "A"}, {1, 17, 18, 19, "A"}}
```

Can somebody explain the difference and give me suggestion how to improve the FOR-statement (or a another solution te get the desired output.

Comment: `For` gives no output. The documentation does not suggest that it would.

Comment: If you have not yet seen this, recommended reading: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12 (i.e., use `Table`, or explain why you think you need `For`)

Comment: Not sure why you wish to remove quotes but if you do, Mathematica will treat them as variables and not good programming practice to start variable names with upper case but you could use ToExpression[set[[i]]] to convert the characters to variables if that's what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Better ways to do this:

```
Join[data, List /@ set[[data[[All, 1]]]], 2]
```

or

```
Map[Append[#, set[[#[[1]]]]] &, data]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
f[{a_, b__}, set_: set] := {a, b, set[[a]]}
f /@ data
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a =
  {{1, 11, 12, 13}, {1, 14, 15, 16}, {1, 17, 18, 19},
   {2, 21, 22, 23}, {2, 24, 25, 26}, {2, 27, 28, 29}, 
   {3, 31, 32, 33}, {3, 34, 35, 36}, {3, 37, 38, 39}};

set = {"A", "B", "C"};
```

Using `MapThread` and `Partition`

```
Catenate @ MapThread[Append[#1] /@ #2 &, {set, Partition[a, 3]}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

The above solution works with any first elements:

```
b =
  {{1, 11, 12, 13}, {2, 14, 15, 16}, {3, 17, 18, 19}, 
   {4, 21, 22, 23}, {5, 24, 25, 26}, {6, 27, 28, 29}, 
   {7, 31, 32, 33}, {8, 34, 35, 36}, {9, 37, 38, 39}};

Catenate @ MapThread[Append[#1] /@ #2 &, {set, Partition[b, 3]}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some more ways to do this:

```
data = {{1, 11, 12, 13}, {1, 14, 15, 16}, {1, 17, 18, 19}, {2, 21, 22,
     23}, {2, 24, 25, 26}, {2, 27, 28, 29}, {3, 31, 32, 33}, {3, 34, 
    35, 36}, {3, 37, 38, 39}};
set = {"A", "B", "C"};
```

```
Cases[data, {a_, b__} :> {a, b, set[[a]]}]
```

```
data /. {a_, b_, c_, d_} :> {a, b, c, d, set[[a]]}
```

```
Table[Append[item, set[[item[[1]]]]], {item, data}]
```

```
newdata = data;
For[n = 1, n <= Length[data], n++,
 newdata[[n]] = Append[data[[n]], set[[data[[n, 1]]]]]
 ]
newdata
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{1, 11, 12, 13}, {1, 14, 15, 16}, {1, 17, 18, 19}, {2, 21, 22,
     23}, {2, 24, 25, 26}, {2, 27, 28, 29}, {3, 31, 32, 33}, {3, 34, 
    35, 36}, {3, 37, 38, 39}};

set = {"A", "B", "C"};
```

The question can be interpreted as follows such that the inclusion of information in `set` is not required.

```
data /. x_?VectorQ :> Append[x, ToUpperCase@Alphabet[][[First@x]]]
```

For a different ordering in `set`, however, the following would perhaps be more robust.

```
data /. x_?VectorQ :> Append[x, set[[First@x]]]
```

---

*comment*

The question suffers from it not being narrowly specified and hence open to interpretation. A better `data` would be one with sublists scrambled with respect to the first element and some indication of the relation between `data` and `set`.

Answer (score 2):

```
a =
  {{1, 11, 12, 13}, {1, 14, 15, 16}, {1, 17, 18, 19},
   {2, 21, 22, 23}, {2, 24, 25, 26}, {2, 27, 28, 29}, 
   {3, 31, 32, 33}, {3, 34, 35, 36}, {3, 37, 38, 39}};

set = {"A", "B", "C"};
```

---

Using `Replace` at level `1`:

```
Replace[a, {a_, b__} :> {a, b, set[[a]]}, {1}] //MatrixForm
```

[image]